# Error:Makefile to compile multiple .c files

Tags: gnu-make, makefile

I am new to makefile creation.For this below folder structure to fetch the required Headers any changes needs to be done to makefile?
The code and file structure as below
**File structure is as below**
[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWzPl.png)

```
\---Project
    +---Makefile
    |   +---src
    |   |       main.c and other.c files
    |   +---inc
    |   |   +---gen_inc3(contains required .h files)
    |   |   +---inc2(contains required .h files)
    |   |   +---Plugins (contains required .h files)
    |   |    |   +---inc (contains required .h files)
    |   |
     \---Build
     |  . o files
     |   output.exe

    CC=cctc 
    LD=cctc -v
    
    SRC_DIR   := ...\Folder_Structure\src
    BUILD_DIR := ...\Folder_Structure\src\Build
    PROJECT_HEADERS := "....\Folder_Structure\src\inc"
    COMPILER_HEADERS :="...Folder_Structure\src\compiler.inc"

    SRC       := $(foreach sdir,$(SRC_DIR),$(wildcard $(sdir)/*.c))
    OBJ       := $(patsubst src/%.c,build/%.o,$(SRC))
    INCLUDES  := $(addprefix -I,$(SRC_DIR))
    
    $(VERBOSE)$(CC) --pass-c -f $(COMPILER_HEADERS) -co $< -o $(OBJ)/$(notdir $(basename $<).o)

    vpath %.c $(SRC_DIR)
    
    define make-goal
    $1/%.o: %.c
        $(CC) $(INCLUDES) -c $$< -o $$@
    endef
    
    .PHONY: all checkdirs clean
    
    all: checkdirs output
    
    output: $(OBJ)
        $(LD) $^ -o $< $(PROJECT_HEADERS) $(COMPILER_HEADER)

    checkdirs: $(BUILD_DIR)
    
    $(BUILD_DIR):
        @mkdir -p $@
    
    clean:
        @rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR)
    
    $(foreach bdir,$(BUILD_DIR),$(eval $(call make-goal,$(bdir))))
```

The error currently I am getting is C:\Users...\Folder_Structure>make
make: *** No rule to make target `-co', needed by` cctc'.  Stop. What might be the issue here ??

Comment: You should always use forward slashes as directory separators in makefiles, even on Windows.  I don't understand the question.  Is there something that doesn't work?  If so, what is it?  What output do you see, and how is that not matching what you want?  Please cut and paste actual commands and (cut-down to reasonable size) output specifically describing the problem.

Comment: @MadScientist: I have updated it!

Comment: Is that error the ONLY output you get from make?  I don't think it is.  I think it ran the command `gcc -v ...` first.  If so what that message means is that make couldn't run the command `gcc` which seems to imply you don't have the GCC compiler installed on your system, or it's not executable for some reason.  In any event, based on the limited info you provide here it doesn't seem to have anything to do with header files.

Comment: Here is the full output for make:..\Folder_Structure>make
gcc -v C:\Users\Folder_Structure\src/Adc.c 
The system cannot execute the specified program.
make: *** [output] Error 1. The log is  too long so I am posting a bit of it ..It goes through all the c files in the src folder but will not go to step of object file generation. I actually want to work with Tasking Compiler cctc-v. but with gcc also I am not able to build single file when all dependency are given in proper path as mentioned in the folder structure. anything problem with the script to find the dependency header files ?

Comment: @MadScientist: I would like to ask you like is there any chance to pass the command in this pattern **"cctc.exe --pass-c -fcompiler.inc -co adc.c -o adc.o "**from this make file ?If so what should I modify? because compiler.inc has my compiler depend stuff and this command executes successfully on the command prompt....I am not able understand how to modify my makefile to carry on this stuff

Comment: Please edit the question with the information, properly formatted, rather than adding it into a comment: it's not feasible to format comments and output like this needs to be formatted properly to be understandable (where the line breaks are etc.)

Comment: Yes, definitely it is possible.  For example in your makefile `CC=gcc` sets the variable `CC` (which holds the name of the C compiler) to the value `gcc`, and `LD=gcc -v` sets the variable `LD` (which holds the name of the linker) to the value `gcc -v`.  If you want a different compiler or linker, edit your makefile and change the value of these variables.  Providing a full tutorial on make is beyond the scope of StackOverflow.  You can use the manual, here: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html#Top and ask specific questions about specific problems.

Comment: @MadScientist:I updated the post with the proper question now.Somethings is wrong here ?

Comment: Please format properly: it doesn't help to put text into the question instead of the command if you don't use the formatting tools provided to ensure that the information is understandable.  Anyway, your error is because you seem to have dropped a random line into the middle of your makefile.  You only paraphrased the actual output make prints: the real output will tell you which line the problem is on, but it's the `$(VERBOSE)$(CC) --pass-c -f ...` line; that's not a valid makefile statement so you get an error.

Comment: I really don't want to go back and forth with every syntax error you might encounter as you try to modify this makefile in the comments to this question.  You're going to have to spend some time reading the manual, and trying things, reading the error message, and figuring out how to resolve them.